# LOAD DATA INFILE - but also add this column entry for every row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Below is the code.

```
    $host = '';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $database = '';
    $con = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database); 

    if ($con->connect_error) 
    {
        die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/var/www/html/cdr');
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) 
    {
        if ($filename == "/var/www/html/cdr/.")
        {

        } 
        else 
        {
            $con->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $filename . "' 
                        INTO TABLE cdr 
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                        ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                        IGNORE 1 LINES"
                        );
            echo $filename . " added to Database and deleted";
            echo "<br />";
            unlink($filename);
        }
    }
```

The current code works as intended. It itterates through a directory of csv files and imports each one to a database.

What I am wanting to do is add an extra column to the database titled "Filename" with the filename that each record came from.

**Is there a way to modify the MySQL query to add specified column data at the end of each row with $filename being the data?**

Thanks.

***UPDATE***

The following is the updated code now doing what was desired.

```
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/var/www/html/cdr');
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) 
    {
        $fileName = $filename;
        if ($fileName == "/var/www/html/cdr/.")
        {

        } else {
            $con->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $fileName . "' 
                        INTO TABLE cdr 
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                        ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                        IGNORE 1 LINES
                        SET filename = '" . $fileName . "'"
                        );
            echo $fileName . " added to Database and deleted";
            echo "<br />";
            unlink($fileName);
        }
    }
```

Was as simple as adding SET columnName = columnEntry to the end of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $filename . "' 
                    INTO TABLE cdr 
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                    ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES 
                    (`col2`,`col3`, `colX`)
                    SET filenameColumnName='{$filename}'";
```

Or even without the column list:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $filename . "' 
                    INTO TABLE cdr 
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
                    ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES
                    SET filenameColumnName='{$filename}'";
```

There are examples of this in the MySQL documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

NOTE:  You should probably use data binding on your query, instead of directly including `$filename`

Comment: @Matt You can actually do this without a user variable, and just set based on the column name.  I edited the above example to show it.

Comment: Just figured that out while going through the mysql documentation, thanks for your help. Have updated question with resolution.

Comment: Updated code in question is what I'm using, yes working as intended.